# How to resolve 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. It works after I clear cookies of the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, iis-express, server-error

I Have uploaded my website and I am getting the following error after some time and after I clear the cookies of my browser, it started working fine. This error often occurs when I tried to open any link that needs user authentication it redirects to the login page one or two times then after that this error happens. I am also using some javascript 3rd party tools for live chat.

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this error by disabling the Web Application Firewall (ModSecurity) from my Plesk panel.

Comment: I had a similar issue in that, if I cleared cookies, it would let me log in, and then after it logged me out (session timed out), or I logged out and tried to log in again, it would show the 403 Forbidden error message! For me, turning the Firewall setting to "Detection only" solved my issue. Thank you for this post 

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, but the accepted answer did not work for me.
By default, the firewall was using the OWASP ruleset, which is stricter and impractical for my purposes. So I changed to the atomicorp ruleset.
more info can be found here.
https://atomicorp.com/modsecurity-rules/